# Registering event causes ElementNotFound exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, notifications, windows-10

I'm trying to use the Windows 10 [`UserNotificationListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.management.usernotificationlistener.notificationchanged?view=winrt-22621) API in Visual Basic on .NET 6 or .NET 7. I have written the following code to create the object and register for the event:

```vb
Imports Windows.UI.Notifications

Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents listen As UserNotificationListener
    Private Async Sub onnotif(sender As UserNotificationListener, e As UserNotificationChangedEventArgs) Handles listen.NotificationChanged
        MsgBox(e)
    End Sub
    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        listen = UserNotificationListener.Current
        'AddHandler listen.NotificationChanged, AddressOf onnotif
    End Sub
End Class
```

I also tried registering the event handler programmatically (commented out in the code above) but received the same runtime exception.

But when I run the code I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Element not found. (0x80070490)'
```

Am I registering for the event incorrectly or is this an issue with how I am using the `UserNotificationListener` API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to create a package identity for my application by running it from within an MSIX bundle and enabling the "User Notification Listener" capability.